# Parameter 'StandardEncoderPreset.codecs' can not be None

Tags: azure, azure-cli, azure-media-services

We are trying to create a custom Azure Media Services transform. The following `JSON` is almost entirely copied from [Create a CopyVideo CopyAudio transform](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/latest/transform-create-copy-video-audio-how-to). We are using the `JSON` from that example to create a [custom Standard Encoder preset for the Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/rest/api/media/transforms/createorupdate#standardencoderpreset). The Azure CLI provides the following help for doing that:

```
az ams transform create -h

--preset  [Required] : In addition to the allowed values, you can also pass 
                       a path to a custom Standard Encoder preset JSON file
```

This is the command:

```
az ams transform create -a <account> -g <group> -n <name> --preset custom.json
```

This is the content of `custom.json`.

```
{
  "properties": {
    "outputs": [
      {
        "preset": {
          "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Media.StandardEncoderPreset",
          "codecs": [
            {
              "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Media.CopyAudio"
            },
            {
              "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Media.CopyVideo"
            }
          ],
          "formats": [
            {
              "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Media.Mp4Format",
              "filenamePattern": "{Basename}_Copy{Extension}"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

This is the error output:

```
Parameter 'StandardEncoderPreset.codecs' can not be None.
```

What we are wondering, is **how do we set the `StandardEncodePreset.codes` parameter?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `properties`, `outputs`, and `preset` keys were not necessary. The following works:

```
az ams transform create -a <account> -g <group> -n <name> --preset custom.json
```

custom.json

```
{
  "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Media.StandardEncoderPreset",
  "codecs": [
    {
      "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Media.CopyAudio"
    },
    {
      "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Media.CopyVideo"
    }
  ],
  "formats": [
    {
      "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Media.Mp4Format",
      "filenamePattern": "{Basename}_Copy{Extension}"
    }
  ]
}
```

An example of this is here: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/media-services/latest/transform-custom-preset-cli-how-to.md